# How to add Company name as a field on a Sign up User Flow?

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, identity, entra

Using Azure ADB2C Identity server.

### How can I add a field for the "Company name" user attribute in a sign-up flow?

I see that `Company name` is a built-in attribute of a User in Azure ADB2C:
[image]

I already have created a working Sign up flow that is populating the `First name`, `Last name` and `Job title` attributes:
[image]

I would like to add `Company name` to the Sign-up form but I do not see the Company name as a "Built-in" user attribute available out of the box:
[image]

Should add a custom attribute? How to link it correctly to the built-in "Company name" user property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all the fields shown on the screen are B2C user attributes.

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-profile-attributes), "Company name" is not an attribute.

You could add it as an [extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-user-flow) attribute.